# DoublyLinkedList method call error

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

Hey i have a DoublyLinkedList and anytime i try to call the methods from the header file.  I call statsList.  because i have the DoublyLinkedList declared to that as you can see here in my code:

```
DoublyLinkedList<int>* statsList = new DoublyLinkedList<int>;

int main()
{
    DoublyLinkedList<Stats> list;
    Stats stats;
    bool exit = false;
    int menuChoice;
    while (!exit)
    {

        switch (menuChoice)
        {
        case 1:
        cout << "Insert";
        {

        stats.Details();

        }
            break;
        case 2:
        cout << "Delete";
        {
        statsList.Remove();
        }
```

But the problem is is that im getting an error:
Error:Expression must have a class type.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Start from the top: Which line gives the error? Is it a compile-time error, or a run-time error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
statsList.Remove();
```

should be:

```
statsList->Remove();
```

as `statsList` is a pointer (`DoublyLinkedList<int>*`).

Comment: Correct,  Im not used to c++ so i forgot pointers would be like that.  Thanks very much:)  I will accept your answer when i am able to.